# segmentation fault in data processing code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>  
#include <ctype.h>

  /**
   * Display the contents of a stream as hexadecimal bytes and text.
   * @param file pointer to a binary stream
   * @return the number of bytes in the file read
   */
  size_t hexdump(FILE *file,FILE *fp,FILE *fp1)
  {
      unsigned char data[16];
      size_t i, j, size, count = 0;
      /*
       * Heading
       */
      fputs(" ", stdout); /* skip address area */
      for ( i = 0; i < sizeof data / sizeof *data; ++i )
      {
          printf("+%lX ", (long unsigned)i);
      }
      puts("Text");
      /*
       * Body
       */
      do {
          /* Read some data. */
          size = fread(data, sizeof *data, sizeof data / sizeof *data, file);
          if ( size )
          {
              /* Print the base address. */
              printf("%08lX ", (long unsigned)count);
              fprintf(fp,"%08lX",(long unsigned)count);  
              count += size; /* adjust the base address */
              /* Print the characters' hex values. */
              for ( i = 0; i < size; ++i )
              {
                  printf("%02X ", data[i]);
                  fprintf(fp1,"%02X",data[i]);
              }
              /* Pad the hex values area if necessary. */
              for ( ++i; i <= sizeof data / sizeof *data; ++i )
              {
                  fputs(" ", stdout);
              }
              /* Print the characters (use '.' for non-printing characters). */
              /*      for ( j = 0; j < size; j++ )
                      {
                      putchar(isprint(data[j]) ? data[j] : '.');
                      }*/
              putchar('\n');
          }
      } while ( size == sizeof data / sizeof *data ); /* Break on partial count. */
      return count;
  }

  int main(void)
  {
      char filename[20] ;/* may not work on everywhere */
      char filename1[20];
      char filename2[20];
      printf("enter the filename\n");
      scanf("%s",filename); 
      printf("enter the filename to store address\n");
      scanf("%s",filename1);
      printf("enter the filename to store data\n");
      scanf("%s",filename2); 
      FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
      FILE *fp= fopen(filename1,"wb");
      FILE *fp1=fopen(filename2,"rb");
      if ( file != NULL )
      {
          printf("%lu bytes\n", (long unsigned)hexdump(file,fp,fp1));
          fclose(file);
          fclose(fp);
          fclose(fp1);  
      }
      else
      {
          perror(filename);
      }
      return 0;
  }
```

When executing the code above, I got a segmentation fault. Here's the output:

```
+0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F Text
Segmentation fault
```

What could be reason for this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the instances of sizeof data / sizeof *data?, especially in the fread and the for loop (s).

Comment: Your question could benefit from a little editing, as the code block is split in two, and there are lots of blank lines in the beginning.

Comment: Without using fprintf() it works well.the segmentation fault occurs only when i try to write to a file.

Comment: Which file? If it crashes when you write to `fp` then my answer is correct. If it crashes when you write to `fp1` then Nos is correct. Please upvote and accept answers that are useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILE *fp1=fopen(filename2,"rb");
```

You open fp1 for reading. Yet you write to it. Change it to

```
FILE *fp1=fopen(filename2,"wb");
```

Comment: If it crashed there I would expect to see output from the previous `printf()` statement. Well spotted all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is usual to use sizeof as `sizeof(a)` rather than `sizeof a`. In fact I didn't realise you could even use sizeof without parenthesese.

Secondly, I am unaware as to the precedence of sizeof so don't know what result `sizeof data / sizeof *data` gives. Try doing `sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data)` instead. It could be being interpreted as `sizeof(data/sizeof(*data))`. I suspect it isn't, but in any case it makes it all more readable and is good practice.

Lastly, are you sure `fp` is non-NULL? You don't check your input parameters (always a good idea to do so) so there is no guarantee that it isn't NULL and if it is NULL you'll get a segfault at exactly where you seem tobe getting one.

Comment: `sizeof` has the same precedence as every other unary prefix operator, just above multiplication, dividion, and modulus, and below postfix increment/decrement, member selection, array indexing, and function call. `sizeof x / sizeof x[0]` is a common idiom for calculating the size of an array in C, so that's not the issue.